How do I test the Generic Type in Blazor
So in the page I have:
@typeparam TItem;

with my partial class declared:
public partial class MultipleDropdown<TItem>
{
       
    [Parameter]
    public TItem AssignedValues { get; set; } 
......

Now I thought that I'd simply be able to do :
if (typeof(AssignedValues) == typeof(Dictionary<int,string>)) { ......

but VS red lines the AssignedValues with the type of namespace AssignedValues could not be found. How can I test the type of object that has been passed?

AssignedValues is a property, not a type. To get an object's type use .GetType or is, eg AssignedValues.GetType() or AssignedValue is Dictionary<int,string>. Your testing framework may have a method that asserts the type explicitly, like xUnit's Assert.IsType<Dictionary<int,string>>(thatPage.AssignedValues)

AssignedValues is a property, not a type. To get an object's type use .GetType or is:
if (myPage.AssignedValues is Dictionary<int,string>)

Your testing framework may have a method that asserts the type explicitly, like xUnit's Assert.IsType<T>() :
Assert.IsType<Dictionary<int,string>>(myPage.AssignedValues);


Instead of if (typeof(AssignedValues)
use
if (typeof(TItem)
OR
the is as suggested by @panagiotis-kanavos
